# Merging of Two DataTables in Large Volumes

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have a Datatable with Multiple rows with Repeated Primary Keys...

It looks like this...

```
----------------------------------------------------
`PrimaryKey CostPrice  SellingPrice   Profit   Address
----------------------------------------------------
101          1000                      100%
101                                             USA
101                      3000
102                                             Africa
102          200         300
102                                    200%
------------------------------------------------------
```

What should be C# code that will Merge the data into 2 Single Rows. I have researched the net but it is not that relevant. I am sure that there will be no Double Data. I mean for a single column, we will have one cell data.

Is it possible to get the output as follows...

```
----------------------------------------------------
`PrimaryKey  CostPrice   SellingPrice  Profit   Address
------------------------------------------------------
101          1000        3000          100%     USA

102          200         300           200%     Africa
------------------------------------------------------
```

What would be the best possible way because I have to deal with Excel data that populates the DataTable with some Thousands of Records..

Comment: Is your `DataTable` coming from a database? It would be easier to fix the data there by using a query to aggregate the separate rows (grouping by the `PrimaryKey` column)

Comment: Could you please provide Oracle Query for this because the Backend Database is Oracle.

Comment: SQL is also okay for me. I will convert it into Oracle from SQL.

Comment: @Heretic-Monkey, a simple SQL Query is also good for me. Please help me out..

Comment: Please don't ping people randomly. All I did was edit your question because you used the [datatables] tag, which is for questions about the jQuery DataTables plugin, and this question had nothing to do with that. Please do some research on grouping in whatever dialect of SQL you're using.

Comment: Oh. I have mistaken. Instead of pinging Martin, I have pinged you. Please don't mind.